# The "FIND" command in Windows 7 Command Prompt

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line

Is the find command in the Windows 7 <strike>DOS</strike> Command Prompt? I tried to type "find" just in the cmd console, but it shows a message the command is not recognized. I run it as an administrator.
Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of Windows 7 do you have? (professional|ultimate|etc) Find works fine on my computer (Windows 7 Home Premium): `FIND: Parameter format not correct`

Comment: I can use "find" here under windows 7 ultimate. what if you run "help find"?

Comment: I solved it :). I tried to run the command from the other path than "C:\Windows\system32\" and it caused the issue.

Comment: Hmm so strange.. does your PATH variable have the System32 folder?

Comment: "Windows 7 DOS" does not exist. The 'Command prompt' and its associated tools are 32-bit Windows programs.

Comment: "Other path. . ."???  I didn't know there was another path for `FIND`.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to run the command from the other path than
>   "C:\Windows\system32\" and it caused the issue.